# ERROR_SMO_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER while installing Sitecore 9.1 manually with no internet

Tags: sitecore-install-framework

Have a question about Sitecore 9.1 installation.

I have to create the installation manually without an outgoing internet connection. This means that I have to install also all prerequisites for databases mssql msi etc. After installing all listed things in the installation the webdeploy throws errors below.

My question is which dependencies I need to download and install (and from where) to run the script successfully:

```
"ERROR_SMO_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER"
like '[WebDeploy]:[Path] C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe
Info: Adding sitemanifest (sitemanifest).
msdeploy.exe : Error Code: ERROR_SMO_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\2.0.0\Public\Tasks\Invoke-CommandTask.ps1:31 char:13
+             & $Path $Arguments | Out-Default
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Error Code: ERR...OR_SQL_PROVIDER:String) [], RemoteException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
More Information: The SQL provider cannot run because of a missing dependency. Please make sure that Microsoft SQL Server Management Objects
(Version 10 or higher) is installed.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_SMO_NEEDED
_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER.
Error count: 1.
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Command C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe returned a non-zero exit code - (-1)
At D:\script-packages\Install91\Installation\XM1-CM.ps1:90 char:2
+  Install-SitecoreConfiguration @cmParams *>&1 | Tee-Object XM1-CM.log
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration
[TIME] 00:01:00
Invoke-CommandTask : Command C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe returned a non-zero exit code - (-1)
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\2.0.0\Public\Tasks\Invoke-WebDeployTask.ps1:36 char:2
+     Invoke-CommandTask -Path $Path -Arguments $msdeployArgs -TaskName ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Invoke-CommandTask'
```

Comment: Please have a look at my blog post as well: https://sitecorecompetencies.com/2018/05/31/hiccups-during-sitecore-9-xp0-installation-on-a-server/

Answer (score 2):

This is an old issue, but a new cause just happened due to [Web Platform Installer being retired](https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/web-platform-installer-end-of-support-feed).

So current Prerequisites.json is no longer reliable, meaning manual installation of WebDeploy, IISRewrite, and SQL Powershell Module is required. Basically, treating certain dependencies as if there is [no internet connection](https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1000565).

For this exact error, the solution should be running PowerShell command `Install-Module -Name SqlServer` on the CM, CD, xConnect servers.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, with web platform installer being retired I cannot install SMO, I tried running your powershell command to install sqlserver but the same issue pops up when I try to install the CM role with SIF, I also installed web deploy manually and made sure it's "complete" not "typical" installation, would rebooting the server help? or what other options can I go for?

Answer (score 1):

It seems `SQL Shared Management Objects (SMO) was not found or the installed version is too old.`. The suggested resolution by Microsoft is to download SMO using Web Platform Installer. But since you don't have access to the Internet on the server, you'll have to download the offline version.

You can find SMO included in the SQL Server 2016 Feature Pack: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52676

Comment: Yes that is what I also thought. The problem is that if I try to install that it says that version are incompatible (to the other installers (which are not from that package). And the SMO does not exists as msi for the 2017 case. (It exists only as nuget package for further usage!) 
This leads me to two options:
a) finding a way to have a current SMO version installation
b) using all prerequisits for sql from the package above (because installing the older prerequisits throws an error of: already newer version installed)

None of them worked for me so far.

Comment: Your SMO and other SQL Server related components (DACFx, CLR Types) need to match version-wise. While you can install SMO 2017 manually by extracting the NuGet package, it might be a better idea for compatibility's sake to uninstall all the 2017 versions of those components and reinstall the 2016 version.

Comment: Some helpful links for the 2016 versions:
DACFx x64: https://download.microsoft.com/download/5/E/4/5E4FCC45-4D26-4CBE-8E2D-79DB86A85F09/EN/x64/DacFramework.msi
DACFx x32: https://download.microsoft.com/download/5/E/4/5E4FCC45-4D26-4CBE-8E2D-79DB86A85F09/EN/x86/DacFramework.msi
CLR Types: https://download.microsoft.com/download/8/7/2/872BCECA-C849-4B40-8EBE-21D48CDF1456/ENU/x64/SQLSysClrTypes.msi
SMO: https://download.microsoft.com/download/8/7/2/872BCECA-C849-4B40-8EBE-21D48CDF1456/ENU/x64/SharedManagementObjects.msi

Comment: Do you know how can we install SMO for SQL 2017, as the database server is SQL 2017 and installing 2016 SQL related versions is resulting into the error that Sitecore installer is not able to connect to SQL 2017 instance

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it may help someone - I just went past this issue, after spending the good part of the afternoon on it, by realizing that I had to install the package on the Sitecore server, and not on the database server.

I found everything I needed (and much more) in the SQL Server Feature Pack 2016 download page: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=52676