# ERROR_SMO_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER when installing Sitecore 10.2 on scaled setup

Tags: installation, sitecore-install-framework

I'm using SIF to install Sitecore 10.2 on a scaled environment, I'm facing the issue while trying to install the CM role on the CM server, and part of the installation is to deploy the databases on a separate dedicated db server.

I've filled in the sitecore-Xp1-cm.json file and tried running it with SIF multiple times, the first part goes through then the below error shows up:

```
>  [WebDeploy]:[Path] C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy
> V3\msdeploy.exe Info: Adding sitemanifest (sitemanifest). Error count:
> 1. Error Code: ERROR_SMO_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER More Information: The SQL provider cannot run because of a missing dependency. Please make
> sure that Microsoft SQL Server Management Objects (Version 10 or
> higher) is installed.  Learn more at:
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_SMO_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER.
> Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Command C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft
> Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe returned a non-zero exit code - (-1) At
> line:1 char:1
> + Install-SitecoreConfiguration -Path sitecore-XP1-cm.json
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration
```

Things I have tried so far:

1. ran the prerequistes.json file, which turned out to be unreliable since Web Platform Installer has been retired in December 2022 (reference answer [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/34254/3547))
2. manually reran all the installations of the prerequisites as per the official sitecore documentation, and following the recommendations of [this sitecore support blog](https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1000565)->

- IIS
- ASP.NET 4.8
- Web administration PowerShell Module
- SQL PowerShell Module
- Web Deploy 3.6 (chose "Typical" setting on installation at first, uninstalled and reinstalled as "Complete"
- DacFx x86 [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-my/download/details.aspx?id=57073)
- DacFX x64 (same link above)
- [Microsoft System CLR Types for SQL Server 2017.](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=849415&clcid=0x409)
- Installed [Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server](https://download.microsoft.com/download/D/5/E/D5EEF288-A277-45C8-855B-8E2CB7E25B96/x64/msodbcsql.msi)
- Installed [Microsoft Command Line Utilities 13 for SQL Server](https://download.microsoft.com/download/C/8/8/C88C2E51-8D23-4301-9F4B-64C8E2F163C5/x64/MsSqlCmdLnUtils.msi)
- Ran "Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WebServer -All"

Everything is being run as administrator, I have SQL Server 2019 on my DB Server.

Every thread I follow online says I need to Install the latest version of SMO using Web Platform Installer, **but it's been retired last year and I cannot find it anywhere**,

So my question is: How can I install SMO without the retired Web Platform Installer?,and should it be installed on the CM server only or on any other servers I will need in my scaled setup? (e.g. CD, processing, even the DB server itself, etc.)?

Comment: Try this one - https://community.sitecore.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=684a410d1b885d10e55241dde54bcbba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your second question, i.e. "**should it be installed on the CM server only or on any other servers I will need in my scaled setup?**"

The answer is it depends on how you install your scaled setup. If you are installing all the roles on a single server and then distributing the things on others then you only need to install it on your CM instance.

But if you are installing things specific to each server role then you need to install it on each server. The thing is this is a prerequisite tool and you can get an error while installing Sitecore package on different servers.

For your first question, yes you need to install it manually by using this link.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56833

So once you click on the "**Download**" button, you will be prompted to select the files you need. And you need to select the following two.

- `ENU\x64\SQLSysClrTypes.msi`
- `ENU\x64\SharedManagementObjects.msi`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you this worked! I'll add an extra note that I had to install both the x64 and x86 versions of both files, but after that it worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

I know I already share it as a link in the comment. However, for better reach to the community posting as an answer. It could be one of the potential solutions.

Sitecore installation requires the MS SQL 2016 Server SMO. In order to do this, you must download both.

> ENU\x64\SQLSysClrTypes.msi

> ENU\x64\SharedManagementObjects.msi

From [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2016 Service Pack 2 Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56833)

Reference Links:

1. [Sitecore 10 Scaled Install -- SMO error](https://community.sitecore.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=684a410d1b885d10e55241dde54bcbba)
2. [Hiccups during Sitecore 9 XP0 Installation on a server](https://sitecorecompetencies.com/2018/05/31/hiccups-during-sitecore-9-xp0-installation-on-a-server/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you Sumit! this worked for me :) , my only note is that I had to install both x64 and x86 versions of both msi files

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark, if it doesnt help I can delete.

So I checked a VM that I have used previously to run a similar SIF install. When I review program files here:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies
```

I can see the **Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll** and many other sql related assemblies.

Now, when you try to find info from microsoft about SMO, it seems to point towards using nuget packages to provide any applications wanting to use these tools with the correct binaries.

So if you go to here:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects

Then download the latest package.

Change the file extension to **.zip**. You will find a bunch of binaries, including the Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll one. My guess is that the web platform installer does a similar thing and then unloads them to these locations.

My suggestion owuld be to try the same and see if it gets you past that point in the installation.

**Alternatively**

If SMO is only required for the installation procedure, you could try manually installing the databases via DACPAC (which you can find if you unpack the web depoy packages.

Then pass in the **SkipDatabaseInstallation** parameter when running the SIF command.

Comment: Thank you Dean, the other solutions worked for me but this might help other people facing the issue too :)